# M/G/1 queuing system with two arrivals

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I have a queuing system with two independent Poisson arrivals with rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. The service time for each class of arrival is different. Let $f_1(s)$ and $f_2(s)$ be the pdfs for each of the service time distributions.

Is my system an M/G/1 system? I know that the summation of two independent Poisson processes forms another Poisson process, but in this case, my mean service time depends on $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. How can I calculate the mean service time?

Comment: The asymptotic mean service time would simply be the weighted average: $$m = \left(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\right)m_1 + \left(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\right)m_2  $$ where $m_i$ is the mean service time of customer type $i$. But examining the transient behavior of this system, it is clear that it is not a M/G/1 queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Math1000! Can you explain more why it is not M/G/1?

Comment: For one, the sojourn time of an arriving customer depends not only on the number of customers in the system, but what type of customers they are...